# Stuck at a problem with an exponential distribution

Tags: probability

So I'm given an assignment in probability which states the following:

One bus in the city's public transport system in one route spends an amount of fuel which has an exponential distribution where the expected fuel consumption is 5 gallons.

a) In one day the city bus makes 50 routes. Find the least amount of fuel needed for the entire day so that the amount of fuel is enough with a probability not less than 0.985.

b) The bus has 50 gallons of fuel. How many routes can the bus make so that we will be certain with a probability of 0.985 that it will have enough fuel.

So I think I got a) solved. First of all the random variable ***X*** where the expected value is 1/λ from here we can find λ to be equaled to 1/8 but since it spends fuel for 50 routes then ***λ=50/8***. So since ***X*** is the amount of fuel then we find ***X*** using the equation:

### p(x) = $λe^{-λx}$

or:

### 0.985 = $\frac{50}{8}e^{-\frac{50}{8} x}$

From here a) is solved. However b) I don't know how to solve. I assume here ***x = 50*** so do we need to find ***λ*** by solving the equation:

### 0.985 = $λe^{-50λ}$

Comment: $p(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ is the *probability density function* which (perhaps a bit confusing at first) is *not* a probability per se but a probability per unit, so solving $p(x)=p$ for some chance $0<p<1$ is misguided at best. You must instead use the *cumulative distribution function* $P(X\leq x)$.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that but it says the minimum amount of fuel needed for the probability of 0.985. Do you think the solution is wrong?

Comment: Of course because whatever $x$ you find that satisfies $p(x)=p$, yields a value of $p(x)$ which, I repeat, is *not a probability*. You need to find the smallest amount of fuel $x$ such that the amount spent, $X$, does not exceed it with probability $p=0.985$, i.e. you need to solve $\min \{x: P(X\leq x)=0.985\}.$ Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it does. So how do I solve that? Using the CDF?

Comment: Do you know what the CDF of an exponentially random variable is given by? Once you recall that, it will be straightforward to solve. Hint: for any continuous random variable $X$ with PDF $f_X(x)$, the CDF is defined as $F_X(x):=P(X\leq x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f_X(x) \mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: OK so if the CDF is **1 - e^{−λx}** do I just solve the equation **min{ 0.985 = 1 - e^{−λx} }** ?